# Call event on first form when second form closes

Tags: c#, forms

I have two forms, I open and showdialog the second form like this:

```
Recieving_Stock_Form f = new Recieving_Stock_Form();
f.Username = Username;
f.Role = Role;
f.Date = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd");
f.ShowDialog();
```

Now when I close the second form I want to trigger an event on the first form
E.G

```
void txtStockCount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Any ideas where I can look up about this or how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ShowDialog` is modal so it will block executiong, so when you close it, the next thing is executed.

You can do this:

```
Recieving_Stock_Form f = new Recieving_Stock_Form();
f.Username = Username;
f.Role = Role;
f.Date = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd");
f.ShowDialog();
// it will continue here when the form is closed.
txtStockCount_TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty); // or assign the variable directly.
```

Comment: This is the quickest and simplest answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

in `Form1`, assuming that your code is this

```
Recieving_Stock_Form f = new Recieving_Stock_Form();
```

You can add the code

```
f.Form_Closing += ExampleHandler;

ExampleHandler(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Why register a `closing` event on a modal form?

Comment: Because it is executed in the first form, as opposed to the second

Comment: But the `ShowDialog` is modal, meaning it will block execution until it is closed. So you always know when it is closed.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that interaction, though it seems very helpful! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather not had cheated with the form; instead, I suggest assigning the value from `Recieving_Stock_Form` to `txtStockCount`:

```
using (Recieving_Stock_Form f = new Recieving_Stock_Form()) {
  f.Username = Username;
  f.Role = Role;
  f.Date = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd");

  // == DialogResult.OK - let user have a chance to cancel his/her input
  if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    //TODO: put the right property here 
    txtStockCount.Text = f.StockCount.ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is two events that you can handle - `FormClosed` and `FormClosing`, depending on your decision.

```
f.FormClosed += f_FormClosed;

private void f_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //Call your function or do whatever you want
}
```